# Distributor and worker end point queue in same machine

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus 3.2.2.0, trying to test distributor and worker in same machine.
I noticed distributor is creating following queues

- EndPointQueue
- EndPointQueue.distributor.control
- EndPointQueue.distributor.storage
- EndPointQueue.retries
- EndPointQueue.timeouts

And worker is creating a new queue something like:

- EndPointQueue.5eb1d8d2-8274-45cf-b639-7f2276b56c0c

Is there a way to specify worker end point queue name instead of worker creating a queue by prefixing random string with end point queue?

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't really make sense to run a worker on the same machine as the master (distributor), NServiceBus assumes that you're doing this for test purposes only and generates this kind of queue name.

In a true distributed scenario where the worker is running on its own box, it will have the same queue name as the master. The whole idea is that you shouldn't have to make any code or config changes to go from a single machine to a scaled-out deployment.