# NServiceBus worker endpoints

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

Im currently evaluation the distributor in NSB and noticed that when i run the distributor and a couple of workers on my own machine, then the queue name for each worker is appended with a Guid.

According to Udi, the master himself :), in this post: [Distributor and worker end point queue in same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102261/distributor-and-worker-end-point-queue-in-same-machine)

The reason is that NSB assumes you are running in a test setup.

**Question:**

But what happens if I run 4 workers on 1 seperate machine?
Will the queue names on that machine again be appended with a Guid **OR** are the workers capable of sharing the same queue just because the distributor is on a remote machine?

The question is important as I did expect to have multiple workers on 1 remote machine and generating new queue names every time the machine is booted is not a good idea for maintenance purposes.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

*But what happens if I run 4 workers on 1 separate machine?*
Why would you want to do that?

Each worker can be configured to run multiple worker threads. This is why it doesn't make sense to run multiple workers on a single machine ...

I would increase the number of threads a single worker is using until the max throughput is reached on that machine. Then, scale out to another machine ... so, one worker per box, multiple threads per worker

See [here](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/862362-msmqtransportconfig) for details on `NumberOfWorkerThreads` configuration

Comment: The reason i wanted multiple processes is because we are using NSB to scaleout an old system which is extremely hard to multithread due to some very bad design. Running every message in seperate handlers with 1 process and 1 thread gives us 100% separation, which means we can quickle scaleout without rewriting old code which is dangerous to thread up. We have tried for a while to implemt parallels but with little or no success. That said i have not yet tried to enable multiple threads i NSB workers. It is possible that NSB has better thread seperation, ill get back to you on this.

Comment: Just run multiple copies of the same endpoint on the same machine. This will give you what you want

Comment: Thx, but running multiple copies of the workers on the same machine is what I am currently doing, but this is also what causes a queue appended with a Guid to appear for each worker (workers are hosted in my own process). Is there a way around the Guid, while running multiple copies of the workers on the same machine? Am I missing something important about the distributor endpoint setup in the worker here?

Comment: Just run them as is, dont configure them as workers. No distributor needed since the all will be competing consumers on the same q

Comment: To add a little more to Andreas's comment, multiple processes can compete for messages against the same queue on a local machine just fine. The reason we have a distributor is because competing consumers on a remote queue with transactional control does NOT work quite so well in MSMQ.